# Foreign key onto weak entity set in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-relationship

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to create a relational schema by following an Entity-Relationship diagram. (included below; unrelated details removed)

[entity-relationship diagram with weak entity set http://nicwaller.com/stackoverflow/er_weakentityset.png](http://nicwaller.com/stackoverflow/er_weakentityset.png)

Until now, primary and foreign keys have been working as expected. But when I try to create a foreign key from the entity relationship `takes` onto the weak entity set `section`, I get an error. `Section` is identified by a composite primary key in the context of `course`, which has `course_id` as a primary key. Therefore, the primary key of section is a 4-way composite key.

The entity relationship `takes` needs to refer to section, so it includes all 4 primary attributes from `section` in it's own primary key. When trying to establish a foreign key relationship from `takes` to `section`, Studio gives the following error:

```
The columns in table 'section' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an unsupported configuration? I can provide more details or the SQL schema if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of attributes in the primary and foreign key must be maintained.

(I was getting an error because the attributes of the foreign key were being specified in a different order than they occurred in the primary key.)